# Emscripten "Permission Denied" even when I sudo enmake

Tags: makefile, llvm, emscripten, emmake

I'm playing around with emscripten and I keep getting this confusing message

```
|[413077]-$>../emmake Makefile
Error: Exception thrown when invoking Popen in make with args: "Makefile"!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../emmake", line 24, in <module>
    shared.Building.make(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/jkirchartz/Dropbox/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 670, in make
    Popen(args, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=env).communicate()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

but even if I use `sudo` I get the same error:

```
|[254829]-$>sudo !!
sudo ../emmake Makefile
Password:
Error: Exception thrown when invoking Popen in make with args: "Makefile"!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../emmake", line 24, in <module>
    shared.Building.make(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/jkirchartz/Dropbox/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 670, in make
    Popen(args, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=env).communicate()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I'm on the sudoer's list, I have root access... but no matter what I do I get permission denied. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, why would you want to sudo here? Can you give more context?

Comment: It gives me the same error when I try to do it without sudo... I've updated my question...

Answer (score 4):

`emmake` expects the `make` executable as parameter, not `Makefile`. Just try `../emmake make`.

Answer (score 2):

All Building.make() does is call `make`. Check if you can run `make` yourself manually on the command line.

Comment: that seems to work, but gives this error: `../emcc -c -O2 -W -Wall -Iliblzg/include -Izlib png.cpp
emcc: warning: -Ox flags ignored, since not generating JavaScript` ... guess I just need to modify the makefile a bit...